# How to transfer songs to iPod 6 (iOS 10.x) via ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ipod, itunes

I've tried almost every possible way, but none of the music players I've tried  would recognize the iPod. Even if iPod is recognized by the OS, I can't transfer songs. Is there a known bug with iPod 6 or am I missing something?

--Edit--
 I installed [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice). I used Clementine,Amarok,gtkPod,Rhytmhbox,Banshee.

Comment: Please expand on your question with further information.  eg. What applications have you tried? What were the error messages? Did you check the logs? etc.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely will not work unless your device is jailbroken. You can browse your file system and download music from an Apple device on Linux however you cannot transfer music to it. You will also notice that the file names for your songs are extremely un-helpful for sorting if you do choose to download them to your PC, such as AMYQ.mp3, FGBC.mp3, and so on.